# Break an array to array of arrays based on the some of item's property

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

I am using lodash, I wanted to group an array of objects according to the sum of it's property width.

I have this data set

```
[
    {id: 0, width: 2},
    {id: 1, width: 2},
    {id: 2, width: 4},
    {id: 3, width: 1},
    {id: 4, width: 3}
]
```

Actually this is to build rows and columns, and the maximum width of a row is `4`

The expected output would be:

```
[
    [{id: 0, width: 2}, {id: 1, width: 2}],
    [{id: 2, width: 4}],
    [{id: 3, width: 1}, {id: 4, width: 3}]
]
```

How do I go about this?

Was thinking like:

```
const maxWidth = 4
let currentRowWidth = 0

let newData = _.map(source, data => {
  let array = []
  if (currentRowWidth === 0) {
    currentRowWidth += data.width
    ...
    ...
  }
})
```

Edge case:

1. if for example the the current row width is 3, and the next column has a width of 2. . . then it should move to next row, since if we add 3 and 2... it will exceed 4.

e.g.

```
[
    [{id: 0, width: 1}, {id: 1, width: 2}],
    [{id: 2, width: 2} ...],
]
```

Comment: How about cases wherein the total width in the sequence does not equal to 4?

Comment: if it is the last row, then it's fine if it's the last row's column's sum width does not equate to 4.

Comment: What will happen if it's in the middle or in the first parts of the array?

Comment: actually, it's fine as well, like for example, the 3rd item's width will exceed 4... it should be on the next row...

Comment: I'll add these details to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proposal which uses an array for the count and it uses all spaces, not only the last slot.

```js
var data = [{ id: 0, width: 2 }, { id: 1, width: 2 }, { id: 2, width: 4 }, { id: 3, width: 1 }, { id: 4, width: 3 }],
    max = 4,
    grouped = [];

data.forEach((count => a => {
    var index = count.findIndex(b => b + a.width <= max);
    if (index === -1) {
        index = grouped.push([]) - 1;
        count[index] = 0;
    }
    grouped[index].push(a);
    count[index] += a.width;
})([]));
console.log(grouped);
```

Comment: The answer is great, but one question, does this approach will keep the references of each object, as for example, the data changes, I wanted the data to be immutable, somehow.

Comment: my answer keeps the reference. if you need just a copy of it, then change `grouped[index].push(a);` to `grouped[index].push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a)));` or copy each property to an independent object.

Comment: I think you should change you answer to match the terms which seems to be added later.

Comment: @mortezaT, i actually do not know, what the op wants - keeping a reference to the given objects or use independent clones.

Comment: Last piece of question says if not matched the width just move to next group. But you search for next matched therefor order will change. Check mine.

Comment: @NinaScholz Actually there is a reference to main result if OP asks for tracking of each object. Otherwise we're in the same boat.

Answer (score 2):

```
function split(arr, max) {
  max = max || 4;
  var sum = 0;
  return arr.reduce(function(rows, item) {
    // If the next column can't fit in the current row, create a new row.
    if (item.width + sum > max) {
      sum = 0;
      rows.push([]);
    }
    sum += item.width;
    rows[rows.length - 1].push(item);
    return rows;
  }, [[]]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a CSS row/column system. :)
Here's an attempt off the top of my head. Hasn't been tested, should be pretty close though.

```
function makeRows(flatArray) {
  var output = [[]];
  var currentRowWidth = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < flatArray.length; i++) {
    if (currentRowWidth + flatArray[i].width < 4) {
      // it fits.
      currentRowWidth += flatArray[i].width;
      output[output.length - 1].push(flatArray[i];
    }
    else if (flatArray[i].width <= 4) {
      // needs a new row
      output.push([]);
      output[output.length-1].push(flatArray[i];
      currentRowWidth = flatArray[i].width
    }
    else {
      // handle your error for a row that's too wide to fit.
    }

  }
  return output;
}
```

If you want to do it functionally, map() won't really work, because it only knows about one element at a time. You need reduce, which keeps track of its output and builds it up piece by piece.

```
source.reduce((memo, item) => {
  if (memo.currentRowWidth + item.width <= 4) {
    memo.currentRowWidth += item.width;
    memo.output[memo.output.length -1].push(item);
  }
  else if (item.width < 4) {
    memo.push([]);
    memo.output[memo.output.length -1].push(item);
    memo.currentRowWidth += item.width;
  }
  else {
    // item.width too big, do what you want
  }
}, { currentRowWidth: 0, output: [[]] })
```

Again, untested, off the top of my head, but something like that.

Comment: I have two remarks:
1. `source.reduce(memo, item => {` ...
here, `memo` - it's first argument for callback function, therefore, correct to write: `source.reduce((memo, item) => {`...

2. `memo.output[memo.length -1].push(item);`
here, `memo` - it's object `{ currentRowWidth: ..., output: ...}`, and his length always equal 2. Check `memo.output.length`

Comment: @MikhailLevsha, yes, insufficient proofreading on my part. I wrote it up quickly late at night. I've fixed those mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be the answer:

```js
var data = [{ id: 0, width: 2 }, { id: 1, width: 2 }, { id: 1, width: 2 }, { id: 2, width: 4 }, { id: 3, width: 1 }, { id: 4, width: 3 }],
    max = 4,
    group = [],
    grouped = [group,],
    width = 0;

data.forEach(d => {
  if (width + d.width > max) {
    width = 0;
    grouped.push(group = []);
  }
  width += d.width;
  group.push(d);
});

console.log(grouped)
```